# Itunes Icon with Flex Mobile

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, air, itunes, flash-builder

i'm building app with Flash Builder 4.5.1, i set in app.xml this:

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>assets/icon/icon16.png</image16x16>
    <image29x29>assets/icon/icon29.png</image29x29>
    <image32x32>assets/icon/icon32.png</image32x32>
    <image36x36>assets/icon/icon36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>assets/icon/icon48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>assets/icon/icon57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>assets/icon/icon72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>assets/icon/icon114.png</image114x114>
    <image128x128>assets/icon/icon128.png</image128x128>
    <image512x512>assets/icon/icon512.png</image512x512>
</icon>
```

in my iPhone, i see the Icon, but in iTunes i haven't icon....

Answer (score 3):

The 512×512 icon is NOT included in the packaged installer (.ipa file) that’s used to submit to the app store, you submit this icon separately as a jpeg. It is however included in the development and ad hoc packaged installers generated from Flash Builder but you should specify it as a .png in the app-descriptor.

Also good to know:

57×57 and 114×114 are required for iPhone/iPod
72×72 is required for iPad and 
29×29 is recommended to include